# Check Boxes multi-select with model and will not compile without Ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that outputs check boxes which is inside another ng-repeat that creates seven tabs, all with the same set of check boxes in them. I have two problems. Firstly I'm finding that when I check one box it selects the same one in all other tabs and once checked it won't un-check again.

I tried removing the model, but then the code would not compile and I also tried using `checklist-model` and `checklist-value` in place of `ng-model`, but this did not compile either.

The HTML for the check boxes is:

```
<div class="time-check" ng-repeat="service in settings.services">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" ng-change="settings.showChecked($index)" ng-model="settings.rules[$index].checked" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" name="check-{{day.Day}}-{{level.LevelTmsCode}}"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>{{service.TimeValidation}}</span>
</div>
```

And the JS that generates the whole the accordion, tabs and boxes is:

```
settings.getDeliveryServices = function() {
    $http.get(resourceBase + "api/service/levels").success(function(data) {
        settings.serviceLevels = data;
        // Get Service Days
        $http.get(resourceBase + "api/service/days").success(function(days) {
            settings.serviceDays = days;
            // Build the Accordion
            setTimeout(() => settings.triggerClick(settings.serviceLevels), 500);
            $http.get(resourceBase + "api/service/services").success(function (services) {
                settings.services = services;
                // Build a collection of all possible rules
                for (var a = 0; a < settings.serviceLevels.length; a++) {

    settings.rulesTmsCode.push(settings.serviceLevels[a].LevelTmsCode + "-");
                }
                for (var b = 0; b < settings.serviceDays.length; b++) {
                    settings.rulesDay.push(settings.serviceDays[b].Day + "-");
                }
                for (var c = 0; c < settings.services.length; c++) {
                    settings.rulesTime.push(settings.services[c].TimeValidation);
                }
                var allArrays = [settings.rulesTmsCode, settings.rulesDay, settings.rulesTime];
                function allPossibleCases(arr) {
                    if (arr.length === 1) {
                        return arr[0];
                    } else {
                        var result = [];
                        var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); 
                        for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                                result.push(arr[0][j] + allCasesOfRest[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                var uncheckedRules = allPossibleCases(allArrays);
                for (var i = 0; i < uncheckedRules.length; i++) {
                    settings.rules.push({
                        id: uncheckedRules[i],
                        checked: false
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

My endpoint is just to have these check boxes load in and each tab's set be separate from each other and when I check them I want to get a list of whats been checked.

Comment: Where does `checklist-model` and `checklist-value` come from ? And can you put the version of the checkboxes when you tried to use `ngModel` pls ?

Comment: I read an article that said that I can replace ng-model with checklist-model - edited to show ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out if I create a dummy object for ng-model then it only checks the one checkbox.

```
<div class="time-check" ng-repeat="service in settings.services">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" ng-change="settings.showChecked($index)" ng-model="newObject[item.name]" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" name="check-{{day.Day}}-{{level.LevelTmsCode}}"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-{{service.TimeValidation}}" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>{{service.TimeValidation}}</span>
</div>
```